# How to initialize an array of struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have an array `cq` of struct `cq_node` and I'm trying to initialize it in a function `cq_init()`. It seems like each element are initialized successfully within the function but when I check each element of the `cq_node` in the `cq`, the compiler gives me the error

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct cq_node’  
103 |     cprintf("exe pid:%d cq:%x pte:%x va:%x empty:%d\n",curproc->clock_hand,curproc->cq,curproc->cq[i]->pte,curproc->cq[i]->va,curproc->cq[i]->empty);
```

Here is my definition of the `cq_node` and `cq`

```
typedef struct cq_node{
  int empty;  //-1 if the node is empty
  char* va;  
  pte_t *pte;
} cq_node;

struct cq_node *cq[CLOCKSIZE];   //this is a member of struct proc
```

Here is the caller of `cq_init()` and `cq_init()`

```
struct proc *curproc = myproc();
cq_init(curproc);
for(int i=0;i<CLOCKSIZE;i++){
    cprintf("exe clock:%d\n",curproc->clock_hand);
    cprintf("exe pid:%d cq:%x pte:%x va:%x empty:%d\n",
            curproc->clock_hand,curproc->cq,curproc->cq[i]->pte,
            curproc->cq[i]->va,curproc->cq[i]->empty);  //error here
  }

void cq_init(struct proc* p){
  for(int i=0;i<CLOCKSIZE;i++){
    p->cq[i]->va=(char*)0;
    p->cq[i]->pte=(void*)0;
    p->cq[i]->empty=-1;
    cprintf("cq_init: pid:%d cq:%x va:%x, pte:%x\n",p->pid,p->cq,p->cq[i]->va,p->cq[i]->pte);
  } //works well here
  p->clock_hand=-1;
  return;
}
```

Comment: The error you get is unrelated to any possible initialization. You get the error because the code doesn't have the full definition of `struct_cq_node`, which is needed to access its members. You need to try to create a [mcve] to show us, otherwise we really can't help you more.

Comment: Make sure the code at the bottom includes the header file that defines `struct cq_node`.

Comment: @Barmar yeah it does

Comment: No it doesn't or it wouldn't get that error.

Comment: It just includes the header that defines `struct proc`, but not `struct cq_node`.

Comment: If `curproc->cq` is an array or a pointer, then the `%x` format is the wrong format to print it. To print a `void *` pointer (casting *is* needed) then you should use the `%p` format. The `%x` format expects an `unsigned int` argument. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: p->cq[i] is pointer but where is it initialized ?